# Generate Random Radius and Height for Cone Class in Java

Tags: java

Write a class Cone to represent a geometric cone.

Also write a main application that tests your cone class.

Provide the following methods:

1. A Constructor
2. Function Volume( )
3. Function SurfaceArea( )
4. Provide Get and Set methods for your entire
   data vector.

Test all of your methods.

Loop from 1-100 and set the height and radius of
the cone using the loop counter or use random numbers.

Output the volume and surface area within the loop.

Code this far.

```
import java.util.Random;

class Cone{
public static void main(String []) {
    Cone c = new Cone( );
    Random r = new Random();
    int x, y;

     for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        c.setR("%d");
        c.setH("%d")    
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what's your question? SO is not a do-my-homework-service. Btw, your code won't compile. And a for-loop from 0 to 1 is a bit strange.

Comment: I know the code wont compile but my teacher will not help me at all. I am trying to figure out how to generate numbers from 1-100 for Radius and Height right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Random is unimplemented

```
c.setR(r.nextInt(99)+1);
```

This will randomly generate a random value between 1 and 100 and set it as your radius. You can do something similar for the height, and then finding the volume should be fairly self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a significant difference between asking for help, and asking for your work to be done for you. I'd advise you to drop out of your Computer Science class if you're not willing to learn the fundamentals of Java by yourself.

Here, do something productive: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/